# iPhone MapKit - Go "Around the World"?

Tags: iphone, scroll, mapkit

I have an App that is using MapKit. I am dropping pins and everything else, but when I zoom out to view the entire world, it does not let me go past the the middle of the Pacific Ocean. If I am viewing California and want to go to China, I have to scroll all the way East to view it.

Is there a setting that I need to turn on, or is this just the way it is?

I do note that this is how the actual Maps App works, so I might presume that this setting cannot be changed...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. It's just the way it is.